# Flex: Resetting prompt of a comboBox

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3, flash-builder

There is a `<mx:ComboBox>` component with `prompt = 'Please Select'`. User selects an option, save it, comes back tomorrow and want to undo it. How would he do that? Because prompt option is gone now.

Just to mention

> I am populating ComboBox values from database and there are thousands
>   of comboBoxes in my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If combobox is closed without selection being made, prompt will reappear automatically.

If an item has been selected, just do:

```
myCombobox.selectedIndex = -1;
```

To remove selection and prompt will reappear

Edit after question revised:

Use a button to clear selection:

```
<s:Button label="clear" click="myCombobox.selectedIndex=-1" />
```

Or multiple clears:

```
<s:Button label="clear" click="clearCombos()" />

function clearCombos():void
{
    myCombobox1.selectedIndex = -1;
    myCombobox2.selectedIndex = -1;
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Will it be in onChange() method?

Comment: Ah, i see you have changed question slightly - either do what ethrbunny suggests or add a button to clear selection: <s:Button label="clear" click="myCombobox.selectedIndex=-1" />

Comment: Is it a better way to do it? I have like multiple dropdowns within 6-7 tabs on a page.

Comment: you want to reset multiple comboboxes in one go?

Comment: May or may not be. I have a page with 10-15 comboboxes. User might want to reset 2-3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra entry to the combo box with 'value = -1' (or similar) and text ='please select'. Then test for this when you retrieve values.

If the combo box is still at -1 then popup 'you forgot this one' and highlight it or make it obvious somehow.. esp if you have 'thousands of comboBoxes' (ack!)

Comment: Can't do that. These dropdowns are populating from database tables. It's all dynamic.

Comment: I don't know your implementation - but when I get DB data there's typically an event called for the response. In there I loop the data and deal with it. You may be able to find an event that you could hook to give you similar capacity.

Comment: That's the reason. It's not a simple list of values from DB. Application takes the list of values with description, PKs etc. It creates an array of comboBox objects. Then populates combobox values from these array.